# Embed Flash into Facebook profile page

Tags: facebook, flash

I'm trying to post a SWF file on my Facebook profile.
The problem is that when the user clicks on the link he is getting transferred to the website where the SWF is hosted.

What I want is for the Flash to open inside Facebook like it does with videos.

The metatags I'm using are as follow:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Title" />
<meta property="og:image" content="ImgUrl" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Mini Description" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Sitename" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="476" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="600" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:video" content="Flash Url http" />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="Flash Url https" />
```

After using https protocol the thumbnail on Facebook has the PLAY icon on it like it does with videos but when user clicks it, he is prompt to download the file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add handler=fbplayer as a querystring in your https-secure url meta tag
eg flash.swf?handler=fbplayer